# Could not connect to mongodb. errno:111 Connection refused

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb on ubuntu-16.04 but mongodb give server connection error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9 connecting to: test 
2016-09-23T12:01:10.258+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused 
2016-09-23T12:01:10.286+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14 @(connect):1:6  exception: connect failed
```

What can I do?

Comment: Are you sure the `mongod` process is up and running?

Comment: Yes, Mongod process is running

Answer (score 0):

looks like your mongod process is not running on port 27017. Make sure your mongod process is running maybe verify with linux command.

If you start mongod process and even then it's failing to connect with mongo command, it means it's failing to intialize, check out designated mongo log file for the reason